# Key frames disappeared

Tags: keyframes

The key frames disappeared, not because of scrolling. Not because of selected geometry, and not because the arrow wasn't clicked. Not because of nodes.

The keyframes in my timeline in the program Blender have disappeared. It's not because of scrolling. It's not because of anything that I can see; i.e., not the nodes, not the selected geometry toggle, nor the arrow toggle. And when I add new keyframes you can see them, but it overrides the existing keyframe animation.

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please tell a bit more, show some screenshots, maybe share your file?

Comment: That seems to be a guess game... so a try "only show errors" (from the view menu)? or the equivalent icon if from the dope sheet).

Comment: i can add new keyframes, but they erase the old animation without showing the old keyframes. I used up all the other reasons like, scroll up! That was an easy one. lol...

Comment: Thanks moonboots. Yeah, I clicked all the icon buttons, arrow, error, stop watch... etc... The WORST thing is that I had this same problem last year and figured it out, but i can't remember how. lol.